# How to apply styles to an element with a prefixed ID?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to apply a style on a recurring element which has a fixed prefix in its ID. e.g. for the generated ID `old-price-520`, `old-price` is the prefix, and the numeric suffix will vary.

How do I apply styles to these elements, or how do i refer to them using CSS?

Here's an illustration of what i'd like to do:

```css
#old-price-* {
    // some styles
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div[id|="old-price"]
```

would select all `div` Elements with `id = old-price-*`

Handycap is it's performance which is pretty poor, compared to the power of the `#` id-selector. Also it has a lower specificity than the normal `#`.

edit:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/Ya9cf/1/)**

Comment: @christoph: I tried this way dont't know but it is not working. I am using Firefox 11.0

Comment: @Christoph: Hey my mistake I was using the `E` as it is. Now it works after replacing with the element.

Answer (score 3):

you can do so with the 'begin-with' attribute selector (of CSS3), like so:

```
[Attr^="value"]
```

and the concrete example would look like this:

```
*[id^="old-price-"]
```

there are probably more similar methods of achieving the same outcome; a quick search yielded this [attribute selectors depiction](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/syntax/selectors/attribute.htm), which can be used for a quick reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use CSS3 attribute selectors like this:

```
div[id^=old-price]
{
    // some styling
}
```

However you will need to add some javascript for browsers that do not support it

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to do this with an 'Attribute starts with selector'

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: He didn't specifically say he couldn't use jQuery, it is a valid answer to the question.

Comment: do you see any jQuery tags, did he write someting about jQ, did he provide code, where he used jQ ?

Comment: Do you see 'I cannot use jQuery so please do not mention jQuery?'

Comment: 1. There are like 1000 javascript frameworks. Why do you assume, he uses jQuery? 2. styling via CSS >> Styling via Javascript 3. perhaps he is developing a mobile site, where he needs to save every kb. 4. Yes, I can use a tank to kill a fly, but a flyswatter just is more appropriate.

Comment: It is one possible answer to the question. There are many ways to skin a cat. You *could* use jQuery to do it, not saying it's the best solution, it is just one of many. It is however, still a valid answer. p.s. Tanks are awesome.